# Out off heap storage

Tags: golang

Позволяет ли golang хранить данные вне кучи (heap) без воздействия GC ?

Answer (score 1):

Вне heap — нет, хотя язык не гарантирует, что создаваемые объекты попадут именно туда. В реализациях, впрочем, разгуляться особо некуда и heap используется очень часто.

А без влияния GC (в *unmanaged heap*) — **да, можно**, с помощью низкоуровневых средств в пакетах `unsafe`, `syscall`, может потребоваться и рефлексия.

В более цивильном виде эта функциональность представлена в библиотеке [Manual Memory Management](https://github.com/teh-cmc/mmm).

Если посмотреть внутрь, там используются, среди прочего, `unsafe.Pointer`, жонглирование указателями, `syscall.Mmap` и `syscall.Munmap`. Автор утверждает, что используются ещё и особенности реализации интерфейсов, так что это при очередном обновлении компилятора может сломаться.

---

**В общем, да, но это тяжело и обычно плохая идея.**

Comment: Плохого не чего нету. Если у тебя map из 10^7 ключей. Это  будет постоянно напрягать GC. В java это делаeтся постоянно(out off heap memory) когда нужно хранить огромные массивы данных в памяти. За "mmm" спасибо !

Comment: @TomX01 это предостережение читателям, которые не очень в теме, но слышали, что GC это априори плохо.